# I currently have an Ecuadorian and Italian passport

Tags: passport

I am living in London since 1996, therefore I have a permanent residence and I would like to apply for a British passport.
Would I have to give up one of the passports or can I hold three passports?

Comment: The UK will not require you to give up any other citizenship in order to naturalize in the UK.  I believe that Italy will allow you to take UK citizenship without losing Italian citizenship, but but I am not certain of it, and I do not know what Ecuadorean law says about citizens of Ecuador who take another citizenship.